# Why was this question "unlocked by Community"?

Tags: support, community-user, locked-questions

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564819/what-is-live-programming-and-what-are-the-distinguishing-features-of-live-pro) the question in question (sorry).

Is this some sort of default that happens approximately a week after a mod locks a question but doesn't take any further action?

Comment: Perhaps it was locked down for a week to calm down whatever situation was happening at that moment in time. This lock might have simply expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, some of the locks we set are temporary and will automatically expire after a set period of time. This time of expiry is hidden from users, though.

Not every lock is temporary; we can choose to lock a post permanently (until it's manually unlocked) as well. Again, whether a post is locked temporarily or for good is not disclosed to users.

Comment: Is there also a hidden reason?

Comment: @Matt Fenwick: The lock reason is displayed as a notice during the duration of the lock, and reflected in a summary in the post's revision history.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I guess I meant, is there also a hidden, more specific reason than "content dispute".

Comment: @Matt Fenwick: Nope. If we need to be specific, we'll usually add a comment before locking a post.